# Jquery -- Accessing a childs value when clicking on the parent div

Tags: jquery, html

I've made a row striped table using divs instead of tables (I hate tables).  I want to make it so that if I click on one of the divs I can grab one of its childs values.

```
  <div class='row'><!-- I want to click this div -->

         <p>I want this value</p>

         <p>some other val</p>            

  </div>

  <div class='row'>

         <p>I don't want this one</p>

         <p>some other val</p>            

  </div>
```

Let me know if you have a answer.

Comment: what does grab mean? like drag?

Comment: Sorry I want the value using jquery

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('.row').click(function(){
   var value = $(this).find('p').eq(0).text();
});
```

Of course, you'll probably want to mark your inner values a little better to fix the inner `find()` selector. Example:

```
<div class="row">
   <span class="row-value">35</span>
   <p>Some descriptive text</p>
</div>
<div class="row">
   <h1>Cool header</h1>
   <span class="row-value">5</span>
</div>
```

Then you could use `$(this).find('.row-value').text()` and feel better about the selector not breaking.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
$(".row").click(function(){
    var grabbedValue = $("> p:eq(0)", this).text();
    // do something with grabbedValue;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can put classes into the p tags, this would be easy.

```
  <div class='row'><!-- I want to click this div -->
         <p class="selectable">I want this value</p>
         <p>some other val</p>            
  </div>
  <div class='row'>
         <p>I don't want this one</p>
         <p  class="selectable">some other val</p>            
  </div>
$('.row').click(function(){
  $(this).children(".selectable").function();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.row').click(function(){
    console.log($(this).children('p').text());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.row').click(function(){
   $('p', this).each(function(){
      alert($(this).text());
   });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.row p').bind('click', function(){
   this.value;
});
```